# Microsoft Teams showing incorrect statuses

Tags: microsoft-teams

I see that this has been an [issue for a while](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/19544905-incorrect-status-in-teams). But Microsoft has been saying it was fixed. But it's still coming up for me. Is there any chance someone has encountered a fix other than "wait"?